# PushNotification software that is proximity based.

Tags: android, ios, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to build an app that will send a PushNotification to android/iOS from different shops as you enter them.

I have seen software that you can set geo locations but this does not help in a mall, where there is lots of shops in the same location.

I envisaged some sort of shop counter top device that would push the notification that was loaded on it by the shop owners that customers would receive when they entered the shop or were within 10 or 15 feet of the shop.

Is this possible or is geo location the only way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

For that you can use **Region Base Monitoring**  in iOS & If you are trying to target iOS 7 And prier you can use

**iBeacon :**
iBeacon is a new technology that extends Location Services in iOS. Your iOS device can alert apps when you approach or leave a location with an iBeacon.
Instead of using latitude and longitude to define the location, iBeacon uses a Bluetooth low energy signal, which iOS devices detect. To learn more about Bluetooth technology.

[iOS: Understanding iBeacon](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT6048)